# How to get child of child of object in javascript. (If exists)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I get some json data, and there I have such a structure:

```
'modules' : {
    'category1' : {
        'section1' : {
             'page1' : [ 'module1', 'module2' ]
        },
        'section2' : {
             'page1' : [ 'module1' ]
        }
    },
    // and so on
}
```

I need to get all modules of some page.

Input parameters are `category`, `section` and `page`.

So i need to get modules[category][section][page].

But what if there are no modules for such a section, or page.

```
    // m = getAllModules();

    if ( m.hasOwnProperty(category) ) {
        if ( m[category].hasOwnProperty(section) ) {
            if (m[category][section].hasOwnProperty(page)) {
                concrete = m[category][section][page];
            }
        }
    }
```

How to optimize this script? It's lot of calls of m[]. Is there a better(faster) way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var categories, sections;    
if ((categories = modules[categoryName]) && (sections = categories[sectionName])) {
  concrete = sections[pageName] || [];
}
else {
  concrete = [];
}
```

You could also create a more general solution:

```
function traverse(source) {
  var path = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var current = source;
  for (var i = 0, l = path.length; i < l; ++i) {
    current = current[path[i]];
    if (!current) break; 
  }
  return current;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
concrete = traverse(modules, categoryName, sectionName, pageName) || [];
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, you could make it a recursive function, though that would probably be slower. It's easier to understand though, and reusable.

```
function getFromJSON(object, listOfPropertyNames) {
   if (listOfPropertyNames.length == 0 || object == undefined) {
      return object;
   }
   var propertyToFind = listOfPropertyNames[0];
   if (object.hasOwnProperty(propertyToFind)) {
      return getFromJSON(object[propertyToFind], listOfPropertyNames.slice(1));
   }
}

concrete = getFromJSON(m, ['category','section','page'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider having an utility function for this:

```
function grab( val, names ) {
    names = names.split( '.' );    
    while ( val && names.length ) { val = val[ names.shift() ]; }    
    return val;
}
```

Usage:

```
grab( m, 'category1.section1.page1' ) // returns [ 'module1', 'module2' ]
grab( m, 'category7.section1.page1' ) // returns undefined
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2f6Ae/5/